# Numpy: Error in broadcasting without using np.reshape?

Tags: python, numpy

I just found out that despite having an array that python shows as (5000,1) and (5000,3072), which should be technically possible to perform broadcasting to give a (5000,3072), it sometimes just doesn't work if we don't reshape them explicitly to these shapes?

I have a set of data which I simply extract them and run, and initially I just accepted whatever shape it was presented with but it keeps giving me the error in broadcasting. I would just like to find out if this error I described is true, or is there some function or things I should do but I didn't which result in an error in broadcasting?

I have alternatively tested out with random matrices of
np.random.rand(5000,3072) and
np.random.rand(5000,1)
subtracting both matrices work, so broadcasting works in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arrays being broadcasted have shapes `(5000, 3072)` and `(5000,)`. 
The first array is 2-dimensional, but the second is 1-dimensional. NumPy broadcasting always adds new axes (dimensions) [*on the left*](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html#general-broadcasting-rules).  So while `(5000,)` can broadcast to `(N, 5000)` for any `N`, it can not broadcast (without explicit help) to `(5000, 3072)`.

To fix the problem, a new axis must be added to the second array *on the right*.

```
dist_vector = dist_vector[:, np.newaxis]
```

---

For example,

```
In [16]: dist_vector = np.arange(5000)

In [17]: dist_vector.shape
Out[17]: (5000,)

In [18]: dist_vector = dist_vector[:, np.newaxis]

In [19]: dist_vector.shape
Out[19]: (5000, 1)
```

---

Note that the shape `(5000,)` is not the same shape as `(5000, 1)`. The first shape indicates the array is 1-dimensional since the tuple `(5000,)` contains only 1 value. `(5000, 1)` indicates the array is 2-dimensional.

---

In [the examples](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html#general-broadcasting-rules) in the documentation notice that the shape of the arrays are *right-justified*. This is what allows for short shapes -- shapes of arrays with fewer dimensions -- to get new axes added on the left.

Comment: Thank you so much! You have taught me something very useful.